# Operations with Asymptotic Notations

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

I am wondering is anyone has something like a cheatsheet with all the operations between $O(n)$, $\Theta(n)$, $\Omega(n)$, $o(n)$, $\omega(n)$. For example, this is something I don't know how to solve:
$$\frac{\Theta(n)}{o(n)} =?$$
There are not many combinations and I was wondering if anyone could help me.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. (Try `$\Theta(n)$`: $\Theta(n)$, `$\omega(n)$`, $\omega(n)$, ….)

Answer (score 2):

Classical resources: CLRS Introduction to Algorithms, 3d edition, pages 47, 1150,  Donald Ervin Knuth TAOCP, 1997, volume 1, page 107.

More formal good resource for such cheatsheet you can find  in [Jeremy Avigad and Kevin Donnelly](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/avigad/Papers/bigo.pdf) article.

And, at end, for non negative case, let me bring some well known properties:

$$ \begin{array}{l}O(f ) + O(g) = O(f + g) =O(\max(f,g))\\
C=Const. \Rightarrow C\cdot O(f) = O(C \cdot f) = O(f) \\
 O(f )  O(g) = O(f g) \\
O( O( f)) = O(f ) \\
 g \ne 0 \Rightarrow \frac{O(f)}{g} = O\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)
\end{array}
$$

For your case: $f \in \frac{\Theta(n)}{o(n)}$, if an only if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f(n)=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do your example,
$$
\frac{\Theta(n)}{o(n)}.
$$
Since asymptotic notation doesn't care about constants, we can mentally replace $\Theta(n)$ by $n$. We are then left with
$$
\frac{n}{f(n)}, \text{ where } \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} = 0.
$$
It follows that
$$
\frac{\Theta(n)}{o(n)} = \omega(1).
$$
A different way of expressing this is
$$
\frac{\Theta(n)}{o(n)} \stackrel{(1)}= \frac{\Theta(1)}{o(1)} \stackrel{(2)}= \frac{1}{o(1)} \stackrel{(3)}= \omega(1).
$$
Here (1) is reducing the fraction, (2) is hiding the constant, and (3) follows from the definitions.

Here is a third way. Let's substitute vague interpretations on both asymptotic notations:
$$
\frac{\Theta(n)}{o(n)} = \frac{\sim n}{\mathop{\ll} n} \stackrel{(*)}= \mathop{\gg} 1 = \omega(1).
$$
We're dividing something that scales like $n$ by something which is much smaller than $n$, so we get something big. We use the convention $\omega(1)$ to represent a function tending to infinity. There are similar interpretations for other asymptotic notations involving $1$. For example, $O(1)$ represents a quantity bounded from above.

I did all of these calculations without any cheat sheet. Instead, I know the definitions of $\Theta,O,o,\Omega,\omega$, and this is enough to "generate" whatever rules are needed on-the-fly. The [other answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/134822/683) contains some useful rules which it is good to remember, but there is no need to separately consider all possible combinations of different types of asymptotic notation. Instead, it is crucial to remember the spirit of the definitions.